# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.buttonClick

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the calculator I am trying to make working.
After I click a button, the console shows such a message:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.buttonClick".

Here is a link to repository:

https://github.com/PRMK01/Calculator

In this calculator, the bottom input will eventually be hidden and is used to write down and evaluate equations. I wanted the upper input to work similarly to Windows Calculator input.

P.S.: I'm very green, thank you for your patience in advance!

Comment: Please post code here as a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. Typically this occurs because when you do: `el.addEventListener("click", calculator.buttonClick)` the reference *calculator.buttonClick* doesn't exist or hasn't been assigned a value yet. You're making an assignment inside an expression that depends on the expression having already been evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is complaining because, as the console says, at line 49 of your code there's an element that has a property `value`, and this element is undefined. So it says "cannot read `value` of an element that is undefined".

This element is `calculator.mathRow.length` : you are asking for `length` , but `calculator.mathRow` is not an array: it's an `HTML element` , retrieved with

```
this.mathRow = document.getElementById("mathrow");
```

in line 19 of your code.

If you try to `console.log(mathRow)` it will print

```
<input type="text" id="mathrow">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this:

```
if (calculator.mathRow[calculator.mathRow.length - 1].value = "+")
```

I had to write .value first and then []. Like this:

```
if (calculator.mathRow.value[calculator.mathRow.length - 1] = "+")
```